# Regex in google analytics to match all except for a string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I would like to match all URLs in google analytics except those with `product-103`. For example, I want to match

```
https://shop.com/
https://shop.com/man/
https://shop.com/learn/
```

But filter out

```
https://shop.com/man/product-103/
https://shop.com/man/product-103/color/
```

RE2 does not support lookarounds. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If forced to use regex that does not support lookarounds, this can't be done using regex alone. If you have rudimentary string search though that is the way to go.

Comment: I was reading a post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611892/google-analytics-regex-include-and-exclude-string-without-negative-lookahead?rq=1). Since I'm new to regex I don't know how to modify this code to accommodate my need.

Comment: No, it can't be done that way, you need either a separate filter or you need a string search capability to _exclude_ that url.